# Reverse engineering website : cannot find the form inputs in the post request

Tags: vaadin, reverse-engineering

I need to interact with an external website I don't own. This external website requires credentials that I have. My goal is to add a user but the external website does not offer an external API. It looks like they are using [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/).

So to add a new user I need to manually fill in a form. Yet I have been searching for the route the "form" takes to post the input I give but could not find any.

Here is my issue : when I look at the HTML source code in browser I cannot see any `form` tag. The `button`s have all the same id "button". When I fill in the form and look at the network tab in the developer tools, in the "parameters" section I cannot see the inputs I just gave although the POST request does appear. The cookies tab does not show the inputs either.

Consequently my questions are : why can't I find the inputs in the POST request and where can they be ?

Please note : this external website is a medical site so I prefer not share the url and they don't offer a mobile app, so there is no mobile API I could reverse engineer.

Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: A POST does not need an HTML form necessarily, but might it that JavaScript is used for much HTML creation? The browser's Development tools (F12) did not help?

Comment: The development tools did help to a certain extent but the js code looks obfuscated and all buttons share the same id, so it's hard to find the "form" target is. Besides that it's my first reverse engineering trial !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not stating the Vaadin version makes that a tad harder give an exact
answer, but at the core both the Vaadin 8 and 10+ behave the same way.
And the short answer to your question is: without another entry-point,
like an API, this can not simply be done using just some POST-Request.

Vaadin is not simply a html-form/request/response-html based framework;
it holds the scenegraph on the serverside in a session.  All
communication is done via a single endpoint to the server and state
changes only are communicated back to the client.

For what you are after, your best bet is to use test automation
frameworks like selenium, geb, cypress, ...

Comment: Looking at the code I could not find Vaadin version, Jquery and other libs show 2018 copyrights. Anyway thank you for suggesting test automation frameworks they look promising for my quest!